# Is it possible that an alias for a website on mac won't open a new tab if the tab with the website is already opened?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, mac

I have a dock shortcut for a certain website on my mac, each time I click it it opens a new tab with the website. In case the website is already opened in a tab in chrome, I want it to take me there instead of opening a new tab with the same website again. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a Mac-specific way of handling this, but there are various add-ons that you can use to achieve this.  Here are a couple, but looks for ones that only need to access your tabs or browsing history - I personally don't allow add-ons (like this 2nd one) that require the "Read and change all your data" permission.  That could be disastrous if abused...

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/duplicate-tabs-closer/gnmdbogfankgjepgglmmfmbnimcmcjle?hl=en

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clutter-free-prevent-dupl/iipjdmnoigaobkamfhnojmglcdbnfaaf?hl=en